# Unable to create Ad hoc network in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ad-hoc-network

I need to create a open Ad hoc network on Ubuntu 18.04 , the `nm-connection-editor` throws up an error when i try to create a new network:

```
Cannot save connection due to error: Invalid setting Wi-Fi: 802-11-wireless.ssid: property is missing
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi Abhiram, welcome to U&L StackExchange. To help the community answer your question, could you provide more information such as the command you're running to receive that error? Please [edit] your post to contain any further relevant information for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You always need an SSID. That's why the error `802-11-wireless.ssid: property is missing` is coming. You have to enter the WLAN ssid.